# Program in Android Studio with Java?

Tags: java, android

I've always wanted to develop an Android app. In order to do that, I've started learning Java 2-3 months ago. When I felt I was ready, I downloaded Android Studio. But the programming language looks very different to Java, and I don't understand even the default "Hello world".

Can someone explain me how to configure Android Studio in order to use Java as the programming language? Or should I use another environment?

Comment: You say *But the programming language looks very different to Java* but what you read in Android Studio is **Java** so I'm not sure what you are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain me how to configure Android Studio in order to use Java as the programming language?

Android Studio already uses Java as the programming language. Any of the files ending in `.java` are Java source files.

However, an Android project will have files in other formats:

- `.gradle` files for the Gradle build system
- `.xml` files for the manifest and many types of resources
- `.png` files for icons
- and so on

> I don't understand even the default "Hello world"

There are many educational resources available for Android development: books, videos, blogs, courses, etc. You may wish to use these to supplement your existing work on learning Java.

> Or should I use another environment?

If you are aiming to build Java-based Android apps, Android Studio is a fine choice. Specialized types of apps (e.g., games) may be developed using other environments (e.g., Unity).

Answer (score 1):

You write apps for Android using the Android Framework. The Android Framework is written in Java, and you will be using Java for the writing of apps as well.

The Android Framework contains a lot of components such as a Activity, Fragment, Service which are not present in the Java programming language.

You will need to learn how to use these components in order to create Android apps. 
I suggest reading the [Android fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.htmlhttp://). This contains more information about the Android Framework. Afterwards you will need to learn how to build Android apps by following the  [Android tutorials](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The programming language in Android Studio is Java. Perhaps you should start by learning the basics of Java before starting more advanced things like Android programming.